# Can an object become a data member of a class without being declared in the member specification?

Tags: c++, object, language-lawyer

C++ draft ISO [quotes](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.memobj#intro.object-2):

> Objects can contain other objects, called subobjects. A subobject can
> be a member subobject (11.4), a base class subobject (11.7), or an
> array element. An object that is not a subobject of any other object
> is called a complete object. If an object is created in storage
> associated with a member subobject or array element e (which may or
> may not be within its lifetime), the created object is a subobject of
> e’s containing object if:
>
> 1. (2.1) — the lifetime of e’s containing
>    object has begun and not ended, and
> 2. (2.2) — the storage for the new object exactly overlays the storage location associated with e, and
> 3. (2.3) — the new object is of the same type as e (ignoring
>    cv-qualification)

```
struct A {};
struct B {A objectA;};
int main()
{   
    B b;
    A* point = new(&b.objectA) A();
}
```

Based on the text and in the code above: this new created object becomes an subobject of `b`, a subobject is: a member subobject, a base class subobject or an array element. Obviously the new created is not an array element neither a base class subobject so I supose it must be a member subobject. So the new created object becomes a member of `B` ?

Comment: _Can an object become a data member of a class without being declared in the member specification?_ No. C++ is a statically typed language. You cannot add something at run-time. Types are evaluated at compile-time and then thrown away (ignoring RTTI for now). What you demonstrate in your exposed code is [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new). And, please, don't confuse "object" with "class". Whenever the C++ standard mentions "object" it doesn't mean "class".

Comment: But didn't I meet the requirements above, creating a new subobject for `b`?

Comment: Yes. And this is constructed into the storage of member `b.objectA`. The other object (stored before in `b.objectA`) ceases to exist (without being properly destructed).

Comment: _So the new created object becomes a member of `B` ?_ Yes, it is what this wording is for — replacing member subobjects or array elements.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat _seizes to exist_ It still exists, just out of lifetime.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer That's too much for me. :-) (I'm NO language lawyer at all - just a plane, stupid appl. developer.) How can an object exist without storage? (Or was it just bad wording? I'm no native speaker. What I meant was "cease" instead of "seize". Sorry.)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer in class members in the draft: "The member-specification in a class definition declares the full set of members of the class; no member
can be added elsewhere." So the new created object couldn't be a member right? So a member subobject can be a non member?

Comment: @Scheff'sCat, but if we created a new subobject for `b` this new subobject must be one the three possibilities: array element, base class subobject or member subobject,right?

Comment: As this is placement new, to me it fits perfectly into _the storage for the new object exactly overlays the storage location associated with e_ So, IMHO it should be a _subobject of e’s containing object_.

Comment: The wording is speaking about non-static data members, not member subobjects.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer. When you say "the wording" you are referring to "The member-specification in a class ...."?
If it is, I don't understand. You say it is speaking about non-static data members, but the text says "full set of members", so it speaks about static and function too, right?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Maybe I'm still missing definition of member subobjects. Could you provide a definition for it?

Comment: @Roman I think this type of situation is one of those edge cases that isn't totally unambiguously covered by the standard's wording. This tends to happen when placement `new` is used in ways that aren't typical (but not necessarily incorrect).

Comment: I think in practice, since `objectA` is transparently replaced (since its replaced by another instance of its own type) I think it is reasonable to give the new instance the same properties as the original object in terms of "subobject-ness". At least it guaranties that the name of the replaced object now refers to the new instance, so to me it isn't a stretch to consider that `b.objectA` is still a member of `b`.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Your first and last comments are the answer; please make them one.

Comment: _You say it is speaking about non-static data members_ I've emphasized non-static ones to discriminate them from member subobjects in the context of this question, but yes, the rule is about all members.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer. I'm still thinking a lot about this question, in your first commentary you said that the new object becomes a member of `B`, replacing the other. Then I commented that "No members can be added". Is this the point? A new member cannot be added, but can be replaced?